# Como fazer o .map imprimir elementos filhos de um array no React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com dificuldades de imprimir elementos filhos de um array. Meu arquivo tem o `.map` buscando um arquivo `json` que contem um array, no qual vou postar o código dele a seguir, na minha função `.map`, eu coloquei desta maneira:

```
{data.itens?.map((item, i) => (
    <p>
        {item[i].name}
    </p>
)}
```

Porém só está imprimindo o elemento pai do array, gostaria de saber como posso imprimir os elementos filhos e os filhos do filho que estão dentro da propriedade `children` de cada elemento.

Segue meu arquivo data.json:

```
  {
  "itens": [
    {
      "0": {
        "id": "2469bdab-23b5-4cb8-90c9-c609a49410b0",
        "name": "0 - Teste 1",
        "children": {
          "0": {
            "id": "97cd3a19-0f1c-4248-a84c-a1f5a0093a89",
            "name": "1 - Teste 1",
            "children": {
              "0": {
                "id": "6410eff5-5aff-46fd-bb08-ed90581007b4",
                "name": "2 - Teste 1",
                "children": {
                  "0": {
                    "id": "35996ee4-74a6-4343-ba5e-9700c24bee11",
                    "name": "3 - Teste 1",
                    "children": {
                      "0": {
                        "id": "59fdebaf-0229-4d27-901d-4cfbb4cf81de",
                        "name": "4 - Teste 1",
                        "children": {},
                        "level": 4
                      }
                    },
                    "level": 3
                  },
                  "1": {
                    "id": "3bfdf6e6-8a30-4bc3-892d-8d5773ee6bf5",
                    "name": "3 - Teste 2",
                    "children": {},
                    "level": 3
                  }
                },
                "level": 2
              }
            },
            "level": 1
          }
        },
        "level": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução seria usar um component recursivo. toda vez ele ira fazer um novo map em cima da children e criar um novo component.

```
function Filho({ itens }) {    //Component que rebe objeto com .name e .children
  const filhos = Object.values(itens); //pega os valores do objeto 
                                       //e retorna uma lista para usar no map
   return (
    <div>
      {filhos.map((item, i) => (  //map para iterar cada item da lista passada
        <div key={i}>
          {"---".repeat(item.level)} {item.name} -{" "} //Mostra o nome do pai
          <Filho itens={item.children} key={i}> // chama novamente o componente,
                                                //mas passando apenas o nível seguinte
          </Filho>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {filhos.itens.map((item,i) => (
        <div key={i}>
         <Filho itens={item}  key={i}></Filho> 
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: você poderia me dizer o que foi feito em cada linha para que eu entenda melhor seu código.

Comment: @Wendell usei um component recursivo. ou seja, um componente que chama ele mesmo. Mesma ideia de função recursiva.

Comment: entendi, eu estou com dúvida em onde eu poderia fazer uma verificação para ver se um determinado itens tem filho ou não, para poder exibir um determinado código.

Comment: @Wendell Object.keys(item.children).length

Comment: veja se você consegue me ajudar em minha outra dúvida neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/533043/salvar-estado-de-checkbox-din%c3%a2mico-no-react