# Como fazer o .map imprimir filhos de array no React

Tags: array, react, map

Criei um componente para imprimir a descricao dos itens que estão em um array porem eles são filhos no array, não estou conseguindo imprimir os mesmos.

```jsx
const RenderItem = () => {
    const itens = [
        {
            "content": [
                {
                    "produto": {
                        "codigo": 27820,
                        "descricao": hamburguer
                    },
                    "produto": {
                        "codigo": 27821,
                        "descricao": pizza
                    },
                }
            ],
        }
    ]



    const final = itens.map(item => {
        return (
            <div>
                {item.content.produto.descricao}
            </div>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {final}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

vc cometeu uns pequenos erros de sintaxe na criação do itens. tem inclusive um objeto dentro dele que tem duas vez o mesma chave, o que causa um dos erros.

Outro detalhe é que o map precisa ser feito na lista que vai ser inteirada. E como o itens é uma lista de apenas um objeto, no máximo seria possível fazer me apenas um item. Neste caso, seria melhor fazer o map no itens[0].content

a seguir o código que com as correções que comentei

```
const RenderItem = () => {
  const itens = [
      {
          "content": [
              {
                  "produto": {
                      "codigo": 27820,
                      "descricao": "hamburguer"
                  }},{
                  "produto": {
                      "codigo": 27821,
                      "descricao":"pizza"
                  },
              }
          ],
      }
  ]



  const final = itens[0].content.map(  item => {
      return (
          <div>
              {item.produto.descricao}
          </div>
      )
  })

  return (
      <div>
          {final}
      </div>
  );
}
```

pode ser interessante dar uma olhada neste outro post

[Como fazer o .map imprimir elementos filhos de um array no React](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/532990/como-fazer-o-map-imprimir-elementos-filhos-de-um-array-no-react/533011#533011)

Answer (score 0):

Realmente na hora de passar para o Stack a criação do itens acabei cometendo um erro, o código correto seria:

```jsx
 {
            "content": [
                {
                    "dataOperacao": "2021-01-29T16:27:13.586",
                    "produto": {
            "codigo": 123,
            "descricao": "agua"
                    },
        },
        {
                    "dataOperacao": "2021-02-28T17:01:28.345",
                    "produto": {
            "codigo": 124,
            "descricao": "refrigerante"
                    },
        }
                        
            ],
}
```

Preciso imprimir a descricao:

```jsx
agua
refrigerante
```

seria da mesma forma utilizando o itens[0]?

Comment: neste caso não, pq agora vc colocou entre {}, portanto um objeto. alais, se o itens vai ter apenas o "content" podia eliminar o itens. mas pode fazer itens.content.map(iitem => (<div> {item.produto} </div>  ) )

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).